# Mouse-scrolling nano in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, mouse, scrolling, terminal.app, nano

In the OS X Terminal, we can use the mouse or trackpad to scroll in programs that use the alternate screen, such as `less`.

This used to be possible in `nano` as well, both for local sessions as well as ssh'ed into a remote machine.
Scrolling would effectively move the cursor, as if the <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> keys were used extremely rapidly.
As of OS X 10.10 or 10.11 (not sure which), this no longer works.
It seems that since one of those updates, I am able to position the cursor by clicking, set marks, etc. (i.e. mouse support is enabled and working), but I can no longer scroll.

I know that I can navigate by a whole lot of keyboard commands, but I can scroll a lot faster on my trackpad, and it would also use soft scrolling, as opposed to the whole-page-jumps caused by <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

Is there any way I can bring that scrolling functionality back through configuration or either the Terminal or `nano`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

| 2022 Update |
| --- |
| With macOS 12.3, Apple has removed `nano` from the OS entirely and replaced it with its ancient predecessor `pico`, **but symlinked `nano` to `pico`!** The below answer will no longer work as of macOS 12.3, since you don't actually have `nano`. I suggest you either [build it from source](https://www.nano-editor.org/) or find it on one of the package managers that are floating around. |

Okay, it's one of those too-simple-to-try things.
You have to *disable* mouse support.

In `.nanorc`, write:

```
unset mouse
```

Or use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to toggle mouse support from within nano.

I hope this saves someone a day of searching.

Comment: Yes, rather counter-intuitive (disable mouse support to be able to use the mouse to scroll). It seems it's one or the other with Nano. You can have mouse support, which will allow for repositioning the cursor by clicking with the mouse, but with no scrolling; or, you can disable mouse support, which will allow scrolling, but no clicking. Thanks for posting this keyboard shortcut. At long last I can switch between the two options during a Nano session. Very happy.

Comment: Wow. Amazingly counterintuitive... I'd really love to position the cursor by clicking and then scroll down ^^ Thanks for the shortcut here as well

Comment: Does this still work with modern versions of MacOS such a Monterey? I'm getting the message "[ Unknown Command:  ]" when doing esc-m, and changing ~/.nanorc to have either 'set mouse' or 'unset mouse' doesn't seem to have any effect. Or is there something I need to do to reload the nanorc, aside from closing and reopening nano?

Comment: @Patronics Modern versions of macOS no longer ship `nano`. They ship the ancient `pico` in its place, and symlink nano to point to pico. So you need to install nano to begin with. I recommend just building it from source.

Comment: Installing `nano` with `brew` and restarting the terminal solved this for me. Thanks for calling out the new symlink!

Answer (score 6):

I tried a bunch of different things, including setting `unset mouse` to `~/.nanorc` and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, but none of them worked.

But I upgraded to the latest nano version (`brew install nano`) and the mouse scroll started working right away.